# checking if a command is running in process with multi users php

Tags: php, linux, shell, command-line

am checking if the below command is running in process,so if true the second user can't execute it until it finished, it working with 2 users but if 3 users execute it,the first one will get executed and after it finished,the second and the third users execute it in the same time, so after executing "ps axf" i find 2 commands of the 2 users, what's the solution?

```
do { 
$ps = shell_exec("ps axf"); 
$res = preg_match("#/usr/bin/php /var/www/html/checker/checker.php $time#",$ps); 
usleep(100000); 
} while ($res); 

$res = shell_exec("/usr/bin/php /var/www/html/checker/checker.php $time");
```

Comment: that's highly unreliable. There's **NO** guarantee that one user can't start your script behind another user's back in the interval between doing your `ps` check and then `exec`'ing the script. Use a lock file. That's what they're designed for. http://php.net/flock

Comment: @MarcB Thanks bro it's working :D

Answer (score 0):

```
$psCommand = "ps -eo pid,lstart,etime,args | grep 'filepath' | grep 'user' | grep -v /bin/sh | grep -v grep";

$command = exec($psCommand, $output);

foreach ($output as $arrayValue) {
   echo $output;
}
```

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain why and/or how it answers the question. Providing this additional context would significantly improve its long-term value. Please edit your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.